# How to disable SPDY on Android

Tags: android, spdy

I want to test `SPDY's` throughput and response time over 3G/4G and wifi through using the ADB extension.

I tried to ‘echo `“chrome --use-off” > /data/local/tmp/content-shell-command-line’` on `ADB`. However when I checked, SPDY is still enabled on my browser. Can anyone provide me with a solution on how to turn off SPDY on mobile?

Also, I understand that I can disable `SPDY` on `Apache` but I want to see if I can disable SPDY on my mobile phone or not.